# Extract data from one workbook and copy to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy the data from one workbook  to another workbook.

I searched through Internet and came up with the below code. there is no error in the code.

The code works fine, but the Problem is,  it is opening both the Sheets , but not copying the data in Destination sheet.

in the code below, I have considered x as source sheet and y as Destination sheet.

Could someone suggest, where i am wrong and what is the reason i am not able to copy.

```
Sub test()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim val As Variant
Dim filename As String


Set x = Workbooks.Open("D:\Mikz\xxx.xlsx")

Set y = Sheets("Sheet1").Select
val = x.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = val

x.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error, lies in the section below:

```
Dim y As Workbook
Set y = Sheets("Sheet1").Select
```

You defined `y` as workbook, but trying to assign a `Worksheet` object to it, and you added `Select` for some reason, which is defiantly **not recommended**.

It should be (if the workbook is open) :

```
Set y = Workbooks("YourBookName")
```

The rest of your code would work just fine.

---

---

**However**, reading your post, I think you meant to define `y As Worksheet`.

And then the rest of your code should be:

```
Set y = Sheets("Sheet1")
val = x.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value
y.Range("A1").Value = val
```

---

**Edit 1**: Updated code (according to PO's new data)

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim Val As Variant
Dim filename As String

Set y = ThisWorkbook ' set ThisWorkbook object (where this code lies)
Set x = Workbooks.Open("D:\Mikz\xxx.xlsx")

Val = x.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Val

x.Close

End Sub
```

---

***Edit 2***: Code to copy columns A:E till last row with data

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim Val As Variant
Dim filename As String
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Set y = ThisWorkbook ' set ThisWorkbook object (where this code lies)
Set x = Workbooks.Open("D:\Mikz\xxx.xlsx")    
With x.Sheets("Sheet2")
    ' use the find method to get the last row in column A:E
    Set LastCell = .Columns("A:E").Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not LastCell Is Nothing Then ' find was successful
        LastRow = LastCell.Row ' get last Row with data
    End If

    Val = .Range("A1:E" & LastRow).Value ' save range in 2-D array
End With

' resize the range from A1 through column E and the last row with data in copied workbook
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(LastRow, 5).Value = Val

x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I added the code, which you mentioned last.  I get an type mismatch error

Comment: @Mikz  did you also change Dim y as Worksheet?

Comment: The error occurs, when trying to open the workbook mentioned in x, while ist loading, then i get the erro, type mismatch

Comment: Ya i did @Shai Rado

Comment: btw, my source file in x, is the xlsx file and Destination file, where i want the data from x is an xlsm file. does this affect ?

Comment: @Mikz you mean destination file `x` is the Excel file where this code lies ? are both `Workbook`s open ?

Comment: no, the code lies in the Destination file "y". only workbook, y is open

Comment: The code works, but just copied the A1, i want to copy the data in column A, B, D, E , F of sheetx, in column A, B, C, D, E of sheet y. How do i edit this code accordingly ?

Comment: @Mikz  you need to define your post once, you can't keep adding requests, this site is not for creating projects, but helping users solve their errors.

Comment: @Mikz the entire column A, B, C, D, E ? just the first row ? what exactly do you want to copy ?

Comment: I want to copy the entire column from A,B,D,E,F and paste them in the Destination sheet in column A,B, C, D, E

Comment: Still there is an confusion with the code, I wanted only selected column data in my Destination sheet. which i mentioned as A,B;D;E;F but the code, copies everything from A till E. I dont Need this.. How do i edit to achieve the above condition

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Filename")
Set sht = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

sht2.Range("A1").Value = sht.Range("A1").Value

wb.Close
End Sub
```

But it should throw syntax errors and type mismatches before. Dont use `.Select`, its not necessary for any functions or task, it can be done without.